# Multiple dependency system config in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, system-configuration

Example:

**field_1** values 1,2,3
**field_2** values a,b,c

**field_2** depends on **field_1** value 2

Now I want to make dependency on **field_3**

**field_3** shows only when  if **field_1** value is 2 or 3 or if **field_2** value is b or c

i am trying this code

```
<depends>
        <field id="field_1" separator="|">2|3</field>
        <field id="field_2" separator="|">b|c</field>
</depends>
```

but this condition is goes wrong if field_1 is 3

Any suggestion?

Comment: When field_1 is 3, field_2 and field_3 not displays?

Comment: @Bill Yes when field_1  is 3, field_2 and field_3 not displays

Comment: field_2 is not displaying that's correct but field_3 should be display

Comment: `<depends>  <field id="field_identifier" separator=",">I,O</field> </depends>`